# Emulate USB as CD?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, cd

So I am currently learning about computers and figured this would be a fun lesson: I own a game called Risk II. I need a CD to play it, I gave it to a friend for 2 weeks so he can play. I copied all the files in that CD to the computer cause I figured the CD was only there for the game to retrieve the files in case the user chose other than Maximum. Apparently I need it so anyway I can emulate a USB for a CD for the mean time?

Comment: Learn about ISO images.  You can save an image of the CD (which includes more than just the files) as an ISO image, then you can _mount_ that image as a _virtual drive_.  Daemon Tools Lite or Virtual CloneDrive have worked well for me in the past.

Comment: @Ian Ahhh, so do I need the base CD first? I assume so

Comment: Correct.  You need to image the actual CD (or DVD)

Comment: *"Emulate USB as CD?"* -- No because it's apples and oranges.  USB is a bus (like PCI), whereas CD is a medium (singular of media).  *"I own a game called Risk II. I need a CD to play it,"* -- If the CD is used as proof-of-ownership, then attempts to duplicate or emulate (using another medium) it may be difficult.